# wxpython, How to display buttons label into textctrl area

Tags: wxpython

I am new to wxpython so i am struggling with this.
I just want to create a button with a label and this label when I press the button to be displayed into textctrl area,for example like a cellphone, when you press one the number one displayed on the screen!

```
import wx


class example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,' Title', size = (205,330))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,("0"), pos=(10, 10),size=(170, 60))


        button=wx.Button(panel,label="1",pos=(100,210),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, button)

    def OnButton (self,evt):
        label = evt.GetEventObject().GetLabel()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=example(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep references to your controls - then you can set them:

```
import wx

class example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,' Title', size = (205,330))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,(""), pos=(10, 10),size=(170, 60))
        self.button=wx.Button(panel,label="1",pos=(100,210),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, self.button)
    def OnButton (self,evt):
        label = evt.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        #self.textctrl.SetValue(label)
        self.textctrl.AppendText(label)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=example(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```